# How to set total number of pages in Data Tables

Tags: jquery, pagination, laravel-5, datatables

I am using using Laravel Pagination with DataTables.How i can set total number of pages for table based on collection .
i.e

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength":10,
    "recordsTotal":3615,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
} );
```

Comment: why you want to set it manually?

Comment: Because i  return a collection from controller and DataTable itself is not picking up the total numbers of data that need to be paginated .

Comment: How did you solved it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

@Awais,

There is no recordsTotal option for DataTable. Try triggering a fnDraw() after you set your data into table dynamically, via fnAddData().

DataTables is supposed to automatically update the pagination component once a redraw is made.

Please try and update if it worked.